# Excel VBA Application.CountIf() not working as in other macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use `Application.CountIf()` in an Excel macro and it is not returning a count.  It returns the number as 0.

I find this confusing because I have used `Application.CountIf()` several times in another macro.

**Working code from other macro**:

```
Sub newer_COA()
    Sheets("BATCH NUMBERS").Select

    'Count total of column CO
    count = Application.CountIf(Columns(93), "1")
End Sub
```

**Code of new macro - `sum_litres()`**

```
Sub sum_litres()
    Workbooks("Small Fill.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Small Fill").Select

    'Count total Machine one entries in column F
    Dim Machine_one_count As Integer
    Machine_one_count = Application.CountIf(Columns(6), "1")

    Workbooks("Small Fill Analysis.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Msg = Machine_one_count & " Number of entries from Machine one"
    MsgBox Prompt:=Msg
End Sub
```

**Output from new macro - `sum_litres()`**

```
0 Number of entries from Machine one
```

I'm creating this new macro `sum_litres()` in a separate sheet called `Small Fill Analysis` which gets the sheet `Small Fill.xlsm` to look at the data.  At the start of `sum_litres()` it uses the function below to check if the sheet `Small Fill.xlsm` is open and opens it successfully if the sheet is not already open.  As this code works fine I didn't include it in my question above.

```
'Calls function IsWorkBookOpen() to check if the required spreadsheet is open
Ret = IsWorkBookOpen("Small Fill.xlsm")

If Ret = True Then
    Workbooks("Small Fill.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Small Fill").Select
Else
    'Open required spreadsheet
    Workbooks.Open FileName:="Small Fill.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True
    Sheets("Small Fill").Select
End If


Function IsWorkBookOpen(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim TargetWorkbook As Workbook

    Dim IteratorWorkbook As Workbook
    For Each IteratorWorkbook In Application.Workbooks
        If IteratorWorkbook.FullName = FileName Then
            Set TargetWorkbook = IteratorWorkbook
        End If
    Next

    If Not TargetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        If TargetWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
            IsWorkBookOpen = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure any row at Column 6 of the Sheet "Small Fill" has a value of "1"? Also, are the columns of the example that works formatted as text or as number?

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your issue with CountIf, but your IsWorkbookOpen function is expecting a full path address, as it is comparing FileName to IteratorWorkbook.FullName (which gives the full path). If you call it as IsWorkbookOpen("Small Fill.xlsm") it will always return false.

Comment: Thanks @Moacir Column 6 (F) of sheet "Small Fill" does have a couple of hundered of value "1".   The columns of the example that works is formatted as just "General" and the values are selected from a dropdown.  I didn't know the format of the data in "Small Fill" as this isn't my sheet so I have just checked the column of the sheet "Small Fill" and column 6 is also formatted as "General" but the values are not selected from a dropdown. Does this information make more sense?

Comment: Thanks @ExcelDevelopers the `IsWorkbookOpen` function in my code does have the full path i.e. `Ret = IsWorkBookOpen("\\Network\Folder\Small Fill.xlsm")` but I had stripped out the folder names to make the code clearer for this SO post

Comment: would the results of your countif be affected if the 1 stored in column F was stored as text instead of a number?  Can you use istext(F4) where F4 is one of the cells with a 1 to verify if a number or text?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is the location of the macro but the solution is simply to not select things but refer to the ranges directly:

```
Sub sum_litres()
    'Count total Machine one entries in column F
    Dim Machine_one_count As Integer
    Machine_one_count = Application.CountIf(Workbooks("Small Fill.xlsm").Sheets("Small Fill").Columns(6), "1")

    Msg = Machine_one_count & " Number of entries from Machine one"
    MsgBox Prompt:=Msg
End Sub
```